# Mac OS X route gateway link#5

Tags: macos, routes, ipv6

can anybody tell me what the "link#5" means in my "netstat" (netstat -rn) on my Mac?

This is how it looks (for IPv6):
[image: netstat -rn]

This is my ifconfig:
[image: ifconfig]

What gateway is exactly meant by the notation "link#5"?

An even more hard question:
Why is the route with destination "fd00::/64" created automaticaly?

Has the "fd00::" some secial "meaning/use"?

Do I have provided enough information to answer the question?

THX!
//Stefan

Comment: The `fd00::/64` is someone misusing the IPv6 Unique Local Addressing. The IPv6 ULA range is `fc00::/7`, but the first half of the addresses, `fc00::/8`, are reserved to be assigned by a global authority, while the last half of the range, `fd00::/8` is for local assignment, but the next 40 bits _must_ be randomly assigned by an acceptable pseudo random number generator.

Answer (score 4):

`link#5` means interface `en1`. (OSI Layer 1)
That mean your packet will be put on the interface `en1`.

And it don't care about the destination MAC Address of the packet.  (OSI Layer 2)

About OSI:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model

Comment: How did you figure out which interface it was?

Comment: @MichaelHampton  1. `en1` is the fifth interface. 2. In first imagine `link#5` is followed by `en1`.  3. `en1` has the same ipv6 prefix (`2002:590d:8926::/64`)  with the `link#5`.